# Unity Input.Gyro.attitude is laggy

Tags: unity-game-engine, virtual-reality, google-cardboard

I used both Cardboard VR api & input.gyro.attitude within Unity, and the first is fast and accurate while the second has a delay (like 0.5s, just annoying).

Do you know how to make the Input.gyro.attitude without delay ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try to update interval for the gyro.

Reference: https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Gyroscope-updateInterval.html

Comment: I did try long ago, but no way to reduce the lag with that :(
Thanks for the tip anyway !